# Next.js Shallow Routing from Textinput Form Submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, routes, next.js

I'm relatively new in Next.js and React in general,

I want to set shallow url based on textinput state in a submitted form based on Next.js example in [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/examples/with-shallow-routing/pages/index.js).

Try to modify it to work with form:

[image]

```
  render() {
    const {initialText, router} = this.props
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
```

But I still cannot transfer this.state.value to `{ router }` / `this.props` on `handleSubmit` so it will display in the browser route...

Please if anyone can give a hint to proceed.. Thank you..

The rest of the code roughly mimicking the example:

```
  static getInitialProps({ res }) {
    if (res) {
      return { initialText: 'none' }
    }
      text = this.state.value;
    return {
        initialText: text
    }
  }

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: 'none'};
    }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    const { router } = this.props

    const currentText = router.query.text
      ? router.query.text
      : 'none'
    const href = `/?text=${currentText}`
    Router.push(href, href, { shallow: true })
  }
```

Comment: Please paste the code for handleSubmit and handleChange

Comment: ok, updated the code..

Comment: Have you defined this as a Component or a Page?

Comment: I need to define it as shallow route, hence it has to be in the same page, I don't know if it's possible or not

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use the `getInitialProps()`, you need to use this is pages as it won't work in children Components. Hence, your `initialText` will always be undefined, if you use `getInitialProps()` in a child Component. In child Component, you need to use `componentDidMount()` and set `initialText` in the state.

Hence, considering that you have defined this Component in the pages, folder, it should work. However, if you have defined the following as a child Component, it will not work.

```
static getInitialProps({ res }) {
    if (res) {
      return { initialText: 'none' }
    }
      text = this.state.value;
    return {
        initialText: text
    }
  }

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: 'none'};
    }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    const { router } = this.props

    const currentText = router.query.text
      ? router.query.text
      : 'none'
    const href = `/?text=${currentText}`
    Router.push(href, href, { shallow: true })
  }
```

Comment: what I mean, as in the example link, you can change state as well from the route, I tried to insert it in `componentDidMount` but no luck